# Conditional formatting dependant of value from adjacent cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

I set up a time recording sheet in Google Spreadsheets. Now I am trying to achieve a conditional formatting of cells depending on the value of other cells in the spreadsheet:

IF value from cell G2 is greater than 06:30:00 (hh:mm:ss)
AND value from cell D2 is smaller than 00:30:00 (hh:mm:ss) OR cell D2 is blank
then set background colour of cell D2 to yellow.

IF value from cell G2 is greater than 08:45:00 (hh:mm:ss)
AND value from cell D2 is smaller than 00:45:00 (hh:mm:ss) OR cell D2 is blank
then set background colour of cell D2 to yellow.

If the conditions aren't met the background colour should be reset to none.

I learned that it is not possible using formulas. Is there an approach doing it in Google Apps Script? I am no scripter but know how to insert snippets and may be able to read and understand if someone would be so nice to explain it to me.

When searching for similar use cases the only reference to Google Apps script I found [was this link](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!searchin/apps-script/conditional%2420formatting%2420another%2420cell/apps-script/0EVIGvRYX6Y/6r0brNiPrCgJ), a general discussion of its capabilities.

Comment: As far as I know, this is not possible with Google Fusion Tables. You can't format a cell. You probably want to do this with Google Spreadsheet.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I switched everything to Google Spreadsheets. How can I do it there?

Answer (score 2):

This should be possible by creating an onEdit trigger for a function like this:

```
function myOnEdit(e) {
  var nextColumnCell = e.range.offset(0, 1);
  if (e.range.getValue() == 'foo') {
    nextColumnCell.setFontWeight('bold');
  } else {
    nextColumnCell.setFontWeight('normal');
  }
}
```

More information on triggers can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guide_events).

Comment: Eric: Thank you very much for your contribution. I'll check and let you know when I am done.
Charles: Thanks for editing the link and adding the google-apps-script tag.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow, I can't also find for a way to directly compare time in Google Spreadsheet..
But I it is possible to convert from `time` to `number` format. By doing so, you will be able to compare the entities.

**1** in `number` format is equal to **00:00:00** in `time` format because 1 stands for 12:00am

**0.5** in `number` format is equal to **12:00:00** in `time` format because 0.5 stands for 12:00pm

**0.25** in `number` format is equal to **6:00:00** in `time` format because 0.5 stands for 6:00am

It doesn't answer the main question but I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

It is (now) possible with a formula.

Select ColumnD and clear any existing CF rules from it. Format, Conditional formatting..., Format cells if... `Custom formula is` and

```
=and(row()<>1,or(and(G1>6.5/24,D1<0.5/24),and(G1>8.75/24,D1<0.75/24)))
```

with yellow fill and <kbd>Done</kbd>.